# Url redirection issue using .htaccess and php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite the url using .htaccess . I tried couple of solutions to reach to the desired url but not able to figure out . Can anyone please help .

Original URL

`http://localhost/view_retailer.php?id=<storename>`

Rewritten url using .htaccess

`http://localhost/view_retailer?id=<storename>`

Desired url

`http://localhost/store/<storename>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules in you root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /view_retailer(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /store/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^store/([^/]+)/?$ view_retailer.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. The redirect seems to be working as expected  but i am getting a 404 page  . I tried the removing everything from .htaccess and the original url works fine. `http://localhost/view_retailer.php?id=<storename>`  . Once i put the redirect in .htaccess , the url works fine as `http://localhost/store/<storename>` but it gives me a 404 error page . the network tab in chrome shows correctly that it is trying to redirect to the url  `http://localhost/view_retailer.php?id=<storename>` but getting a 404 error.

Comment: Same issue . No luck

Comment: Full .htaccess `Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /

<FilesMatch "\.inc.php">
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /view_retailer(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /store/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(admin)($|/) - [L]
# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^store/([\w-]+)/?$ view_retailer.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
` . Both the file are located under www folder .

Comment: .htaccess now looks like `RewriteEngine On

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^store/([\w-]+)/?$ view_retailer.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

`   url tested : http://localhost/store/flipkart.com and now it says The requested URL /store/Flipkart.com was not found on this server.